# Why the select -first 1 doesn't work in this PowerShell command?

Tags: powershell, failovercluster

I'm testing in a Windows Failover cluster environment. Below is my code.

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.DEV> Get-ClusterResource *disk*

Name           State  OwnerGroup        ResourceType
----           -----  ----------        ------------
Cluster Disk 1 Online Available Storage Physical Disk
Cluster Disk 2 Online Cluster Group     Physical Disk
Cluster Disk 3 Online Available Storage Physical Disk


PS C:\Users\administrator.DEV> (Get-ClusterResource *disk*).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS C:\Users\administrator.DEV> (Get-ClusterResource *disk*)[0].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    ClusterResource                          Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterObject

PS C:\Users\administrator.DEV>
```

As you can see, I have three disk resource. But when I want to get the first one with the `select` cmdlet, I got empty output.

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.DEV> Get-ClusterResource *disk* | select -First 1

PS C:\Users\administrator.DEV>
```

Why this behavior? How can I get the first disk resource in this case?

Comment: What happens if you try this? `Get-ClusterResource *disk* | Write-Output | Select-Object -First 1` // if that works, it's because that cmdlet is not enumerating it's output

Comment: Does `Select -Index 0` make a difference?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It generates empty output.

Comment: @Metzli_Tonaltzintli It generates empty output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, [`Get-ClusterResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/failoverclusters/get-clusterresource) exhibits *nonstandard behavior* by emitting an *array* of results *as a whole* (as a single object) rather than *enumerating* it, i.e. emitting its elements *one by one* (the latter is what cmdlets are generally expected to do).

Therefore, either use 
`(Get-ClusterResource *disk*) | select -First 1` (note the `(...)` to force *enumeration* of the array), or - as you're already showing - simply index directly into the array: 
`(Get-ClusterResource *disk*)[0]`